# jmeter 2.13 picking post parameters from a file

Tags: jmeter

I need to pick request body parameters from a file. I am using jmeter 2.13.
CSV data config is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XRgm.png)

and my request looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpjJl.png)

Upon running the tests, I see that some request are able to pick the param correctly while some are not, and hence fail.

Here is my data file

[data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrhoM.png)

Comment: Try delimiter `,`

Comment: I tried already. Same behaviour

Comment: Are you getting <EOF> in place of parameter for failed request? If yes, open your csv and deleted some rows below your data and check. Share request and response if this is not the case for quick answer.